# create a new matrix from values obtained iterating through other matricies

Tags: matlab

In Matlab I  have 4 matricies which are all 1(row) by 4(coloumns) (ABDC, EFGH, IJKL, MNOP)

Their names are also stored in a list

Stock_List2 = {'ABCD'    'EFGH'    'IJKL'    'MNOP'}  and is a 1 by 4 cell.

I want to iterate through the list and create a new matrix called "display"  which takes the values of the indvidual matricies and places them underneath each other)

I am trying something like

```
for e = 1:length(Stock_List2)
   display(e) = eval(strcat(Stock_List2)(e))
end
```

Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.

However getting the following error expression which truthfully may well just be that I'm way off the mark.

As an example if  the orginal matricies are as follows:

```
ABCD         1  2  3   4
DEFG         5  6  7   8
HIJK         9  8  7   6
LMNO         5  4  3   2
```

I would like the final output ie the 'display matrix to be a 4 by 4 matrix looking like

display

```
1 2 3 4   
5 6 7 8
9 8 7 6 
5 4 3 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to create an array that is `4x4`? That's what I understand when you say `"stacking underneath each other"`. Or do you want a cell array that is `4x1`, each with a `1x4` matrix inside? I think you need to update your question and make it more clear.

Comment: I would also suggest using another name than `display` for your matrix as its a Matlab function.

Comment: Not really sure what you want, but I think `vertcat` may be what you are after, `printout = vertcat(Stock_List2{:})`

Comment: The contents of the 4 matrices are above.

Comment: The contents of the 4 matrices are above. I want to iterate through the matrices and create a new matrix which has the contents of the matrices in the new matrix.  so step one go into matrix ABCD  and take the 4 values and put them into the display_matrix   in line one. Then move to matrix EFGH  and take the 4 values and append them to display_matrix at row 2. Then move to matrix IJKL and take the 4 values and append them to display_matrix in row 3.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right you want to concatenate vertically the matrices ABDC, EFGH, IJKL and MNOP saving them in the matrix "display".

You could do:

```
display = [ABDC; EFGH; IJKL; MNOP]
```

or:

```
for i=1:length(Stock_List2)
    display(i,:) = Stock_List2{i}
end
```

Comment: Both solutions above  appear to vertcat the names of the matricies ie they return   ABCD, EFGH,  etc - what we want to to is vertcat if you like what is inside the various matrices - hence why I was assuming the need to use the eval statement

Comment: What do you mean by " if you like what is inside the various matrices"?

Comment: Also, I've tested both solutions, they vertcat the matrices, not the names.
But you can always use vertcat anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if what I wanted wasnt clear - I've got the following from a colleague which achieves the desired result

```
for e=1:length(Stock_List2)
    eval(strcat('display_mat(e,:) = ',Stock_List2{e}));
end
```